# Webform two dependent select lists

Tags: webforms

I have a content type "course" and a taxonomy vocabulary "Course categories" and a Webform
"Register" the user will register by choosing the course category in select list then use the course related to this term .

Now i have a list for terms and a list for courses 
The problem is i don't know how to link between the two lists so the courses list show only
the correct course

Comment: Means you have some courses & some category also. You want to display courses as per category select. You can do this by creating custom template file & you can easily relate both & show courses as per both.

Answer (score 0):

Install [conditional fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module and it creates relationship between fields.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Client-side Hierarchical Select module](https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs) with [a patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs/issues/3166046) that gets it to work for webforms too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).